# How can Set limit maximum 10 orders on specific time interval Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, orders, checkout-page, delivery-date, delivery-time

I am using delivery date extension which date & time options. Time options has 2 hours difference in each interval. I want to set order limit within time interval.

For example:

> Time Interval:
>
> 9-11, 11-13, 13-15, 15-17

I want to set limit to maximum 10 orders within one time interval.

After 10 orders that specific time interval must be disabled.

How can I do this task? can anyone help to do this?

datepicker.js is used to change date. How can I call controller to add my php code or condition for this. Here is the datepicker.js code:

```
  define([
        'moment',
        'ko',
        'underscore',
        'jquery',
        'mage/translate',
        'mage/calendar'
    ], function (moment, ko, _, $, $t) {
        'use strict';

        var defaults = {
            dateFormat: 'mm\/dd\/yyyy',
            showsTime: false,
            timeFormat: null,
            buttonImage: null,
            buttonImageOnly: null,
            buttonText: $t('Select Date')
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.amastydatepicker = {

            init: function (el, valueAccessor) {

                var config = valueAccessor(),
                    observable,
                    options = {};

                _.extend(options, defaults);

                if (typeof config === 'object') {
                    observable = config.storage;

                    _.extend(options, config.options);
                } else {
                    observable = config;
                }

                var date = moment(observable(), config.elem.pickerDateTimeFormat);

                $(el).calendar(options);
                observable() && $(el).datepicker('setDate', date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                $(el).blur();

                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(el, 'change', function () {
=========================================================================
                    //alert(this.value); 
                    // date changed from here. I want to call controller from here
=========================================================================
                    observable(this.value);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve Order Limit functionality for each delivery Slot you can use the below approach:

1. In your delivery date extension where you have date & time options, you can create one more field as order limit. So each delivery slot can have different limit.
2. In `sales_order` table you must have `delivery date and time` field. So before displaying "delivery slots" on checkout you need to add one more check to mark delivery slot enable or disable in checkout. like below function:

   ```
   public function checkOrderLimit($date, $time, $maxCount)
   {

   $cancelled = 'canceled';
   $closed  = 'closed';

   $connection = $this->getConnection();
   $select     = $connection->select()
       ->from($this->resource->getTableName('sales_order'), 'COUNT(entity_id)')
       ->where('delivery_slot_realtime=?', $time)
       ->where('delivery_date=?', $date)
       ->where('state!=?', $cancelled)
       ->where('state!=?', $closed);

   $totalOrderCount = (int) $connection->fetchOne($select);

   if ($totalOrderCount >= $maxCount)
       return false;
   else
       return true;
   }
   ```

Hope this help !!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, There is only lower and upper limit options for time interval.

Comment: yes that you need to customize to add order limit as well

Answer (score 0):

Since the Question is related to logic, need more detail about how the extension works as a flow.

Once the delivery date was chosen, try to trigger an Ajax action, where filter the orders with the delivery date

```
$connection = $this->getConnection();
$select     = $connection->select()
    ->from($this->resource->getTableName('sales_order'), 'COUNT(entity_id)')
    ->where('delivery_date=?', $date)
    ->where('state!=?', $cancelled)
    ->where('state!=?', $closed)
    ->group('delivery_slot');
```

Based on the count, you can disable the unavailable slot at the Ajax ends time.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have added datepicker.js code where date changed. I want to call controller from here so that I can do

Comment: Yes. Onchange of deleivery_date field you can call controller action. Happy to know that it was helped to you.